# Please add a reference to Mono.Android.Export.dll when using ExportAttribute or ExportFieldAttribute

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am facing an issue on Targeting to Android 13 in Xamarin Project. Please any one suggest some solution, we are stuck on this.

I have updated all the nuget packages to the latest version due the issue with Firebase notification not working on Android 13 after that I am getting build error.

I am using VS 2022 version 17.5.4

Error message

```
5>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1509,3): error XA4210: Please add a reference to Mono.Android.Export.dll when using ExportAttribute or ExportFieldAttribute.
```

Comment: Did you actually do what the error suggests? It is not a package reference.